# Adding a Timeout to Try / Catch Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following script:

```
$primary = (import-csv "C:\AutoTasks\assets.txt" | 
    % {new-object psobject -property $([ordered] @{
    "Asset Number"=$_.Computer;
    "Region"=$_.Description; 
    "Online Status"=(test-connection -computername $_.Computer -quiet -count 1);
    "Online Since"= Try {(([Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime((gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_.Computer -ErrorAction Stop).LastBootUpTime)))} Catch {"Offline"} ;        
    "Free Disk Space (GB)" = Try { ([Math]::Round(((get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $_.Computer -Filter $_.Drive -ErrorAction Stop).freespace)/1Gb,2)) } Catch {"Offline"};
    "Free Disk Space %" = Try {([Math]::Round(100*(([Math]::Round(((get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $_.Computer -Filter $_.Drive -ErrorAction Stop).freespace)/1Gb,2)) / ([Math]::Round(((get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $_.Computer -Filter $_.Drive).size)/1Gb,2))),2))} Catch {"Offline"}
        })} | ConvertTo-HTML -as Table -Fragment |Out-String)
```

...and it works, works just as designed. If the asset is online, it fills the table with the relevant data, if the asset is offline then it will fill the columns with 'offline'.

My issue concerns runtime. For an asset that is online, the script completes in 0.8 seconds. For an asset that is offline, it takes 1 minute 51 seconds. This is because the Try for Online Since, Free Disk Space (GB), and Free Disk Space % are all taking an age to fail, before finally settling on the Catch.

Is there any way to speed this up, so that the Try will end after 5 seconds, or would I need to rewrite the whole block in a different format?

I've read the other posts on the site, but a lot refer back to wait-job and stop-job, which I don't think I can use here.

**Edit:**

By replacing Try / Catch with If / Else, I have the following script, and run time for an offline machine is down to 12 seconds:

```
$primary = (import-csv "C:\AutoTasks\assets.txt" | 
    % {new-object psobject -property $([ordered] @{
    "Asset Number"=$_.Computer;
    "Region"=$_.Description; 
    "Online Status"=(test-connection -computername $_.Computer -quiet -count 1);
    "Online Since"= if ((test-connection -computername $_.Computer -quiet -count 1)) {(([Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime((gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_.Computer -ErrorAction Stop).LastBootUpTime)))} Else {"Offline"} ;
    "Disk Size (GB)" = if ((test-connection -computername $_.Computer -quiet -count 1)) {([Math]::Round(((get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $_.Computer -Filter $_.Drive -ErrorAction Stop).size)/1Gb,2 )) } Else {"Offline"};
    "Free Disk Space (GB)" = if ((test-connection -computername $_.Computer -quiet -count 1)) { ([Math]::Round(((get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $_.Computer -Filter $_.Drive -ErrorAction Stop).freespace)/1Gb,2)) } Else {"Offline"};
    "Free Disk Space %" = if ((test-connection -computername $_.Computer -quiet -count 1)) {([Math]::Round(100*(([Math]::Round(((get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $_.Computer -Filter $_.Drive -ErrorAction Stop).freespace)/1Gb,2)) / ([Math]::Round(((get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername $_.Computer -Filter $_.Drive).size)/1Gb,2))),2))} Else {"Offline"};
       })} |Out-String)
```

Is there a way of me setting a variable within the array, or am I stuck with the way I have it, as in, the same if statements on each line?

Comment: easiest way to achieve that - use an `if` statement, so try getting data from a PC only if its pingable

Comment: Cheers, replaced with if statements and edited original post.

Comment: please, create another question for your second question ;)